# How to narrow type to object and exclude boolean type?

Tags: typescript

I am stuck in simple example, tried different tricks to narrow type but TS giving me errors.
Consider following example:

```
interface IObject {
    someField: string
}

interface ISomething {
    inner:  IObject | boolean
}

function returnValue(s: string, smth: ISomething): string {
    if (s === 'inner')
        return smth[s].someField
    else 
        return ''
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArCCzIDeAUMmcgM4D2AthAGLAQA2AJgFyVhSgDmxAX2LFQkWIhSoAyrQhgAFnyKlyoENE5osufMgA+yTFSrMIcEIOEwAriHzAqIZFDnWoIAGpxm1iAAoKTgpuPgAaShoFTmlZBT4ASiCQkF5lcmRgGGQA5ABefOQAcjVoQviVdLIXMDcnCkj5AG0KAF0AOmo6RhZWCuQWChQ+9OraosLBIA)

**How would you tell TS that smth['inner'] is of type IObject**, excluding boolean type so TS won't error: *Property 'someField' does not exist on type 'boolean | IObject'.
Property 'someField' does not exist on type 'false'.(2339)*

Comment: You need to add an extra condition. [example](https://tsplay.dev/WJ41ZN) or [with negation](https://tsplay.dev/w24vxm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an extra condition statement:

```js
interface IObject {
    someField: string
}

interface ISomething {
    inner: IObject | boolean
}

function returnValue(s: string, smth: ISomething) {
    if (s === 'inner') {
        const value = smth[s];
      // Or typeof value === 'object'
        if (typeof value !== 'boolean') {
            return value.someField
        }
    }

    return ''
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w24vxm)

I think this is a good place to use function overloadings. COnsider this example:

```js
interface IObject<SomeField> {
    someField: SomeField
}

interface ISomething<T> {
    inner: IObject<T> | boolean
}

function returnValue(s: 'inner', smth: { inner: boolean }): ''
function returnValue<SomeField extends string>(s: 'inner', smth: ISomething<SomeField>): SomeField
function returnValue(s: string, smth: ISomething<string>): ''
function returnValue(s: string, smth: ISomething<string>) {
    if (s === 'inner') {
        const value = smth[s];
        if (typeof value !== 'boolean') {
            return value.someField
        }
    }

    return ''
}

const result1 = returnValue('inner', { inner: { someField: 'hello' } }) // "hello"
const result2 = returnValue('inner', { inner: true }) // ""
const result3 = returnValue('other', { inner: true }) // ""
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBjBgN)

Comment: I just don't understand why TS can evaluate type from: s === 'inner' && smth[s], but won't narrow type if we use: if (typeof smth[s] !== 'object').

Comment: This is because `smth[s]` uses computed key `s` and TS does not support this . In such cases you should assign `smth[s]` to some variable and than try to narrow it. This is why I have created `value` const

Comment: There should be another reason. TS can use computed key for type checking. This is why we are seeing error (property someField doesn't exist on boolean) after comparing s to 'inner'(if s === 'inner') and then accessing smth[s].someField

Comment: @Anton the reason is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530; it's an outstanding issue that hasn't been fixed because the fix slowed down the compiler too much to be worth it.

Answer (score -1):

```
(<ISomething>smth['inner']).someField
```

This should work

You can check for type of `if(smth['inner'] instanceof boolean)`

Then you can write if statements with that

Comment: what if `inner` is a boolean?

Comment: then you need to check for type

Comment: That is not a good way. We are forcing TS to make smth['inner'] be of ISomething type. As @captain-yossarian suggested it could be boolean, than we will get reference error for .someField operation

Comment: "then you need to check for type" - this is what my question is here. How to properly check for a type in this situation

Comment: if(smth['inner'] instanceof boolean) - have you tried code in any TS-enabled editor ? It still errors, and i need to narrow to ISomething-object type not to boolean